# Attempting to add listener to barba.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Using [barba.js](http://barbajs.org/) to make an SPA site, but I'm having trouble getting another plugin I'm using ([fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)) to fire after page content is updated.**

Right now I have to click every link twice to trigger fullpage.js
[image]

This is the function I need to run after barba.js modifies the DOM:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  //Scrolling
  autoScrolling:false,
  scrollingSpeed: 2500,
  easing: 'swing',
  fitToSection: false,
 });
```

I tried this:

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('initStateChange', function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //Scrolling
    autoScrolling:false,
    scrollingSpeed: 2500,
    easing: 'swing',
    fitToSection: false,
 });
});
```

...but nothing happens.

Scripts included:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/footer-reveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.smoothState.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact.js"></script>
<script src="js/barba.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ncscripts.js"></script>
```

**Content of 'ncscripts.js', where all my functions live:**

```
Barba.Pjax.start();

Barba.Dispatcher.on('initStateChange', function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //Scrolling
    autoScrolling:false,
    scrollingSpeed: 2500,
    easing: 'swing',
    fitToSection: false,
 });
});

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  //Scrolling
  autoScrolling:false,
  scrollingSpeed: 2500,
  easing: 'swing',
  fitToSection: false,
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#close-button').click(function() {
    $('#gallery').toggleClass('hidden');
 });
});

$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.cloak-hide').toggleClass('cloak-hide-active');
});

$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.menu-transform').toggleClass('menu-transform-active');
});

$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.resp-font-menu').toggleClass('resp-font-menu-transition-active');
});

$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.menu-footer-content').toggleClass
 ('menu-footer-content-transition-active');
});

$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.logo-black').toggleClass('logo-black-active');
});

$('.burger').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-left").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-left').toggleClass('bar-active');
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-middle").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-middle').toggleClass('bar-active');
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-right").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-right').toggleClass('bar-active');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#logo-black').css({'opacity':(( 60-scroll )/60)});
});

$('#container-master').footerReveal();
```

Not sure how to move forward. Any advice/constructive criticism/feedback regarding this issue would be monumentally helpful!

*Also, I'm not sure if my arrangement of functions in 'ncscript.js' is optimal (or even 'correct'). Any advice regarding best practices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up fixing my issue:

```
initFullpagePlugin();

function initFullpagePlugin (parentElement) {
var element;

element = parentElement ? $('#fullpage', parentElement) : $('#fullpage');

if (element.length) {

  // Destroys old fullPage.js object in memory,
  // removes elements from DOM
  if ($.fn.fullpage.destroy) {
    $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
  }

  element.fullpage({
    //Scrolling
    autoScrolling:false,
    scrollingSpeed: 2500,
    easing: 'swing',
    fitToSection: false
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(current, prev, newContainer) {
$(newContainer).find('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //Scrolling
    autoScrolling:false,
    scrollingSpeed: 2500,
    easing: 'swing',
    fitToSection: false,
 });
});
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the advice. I've implemented this but it's behaving strangely. For instance, on first load & after refreshing index.html, fullpage fails to start. But after clicking on the 'work' link and returning to index, fullpage is active.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working as is, any advice as to how I should proceed?  Should I try triggering the fullpage.js listener using the view functionality barba.js details?

Comment: Hey there Luigi, It seems like the code you shared should work, but I'm still having no luck. I'm trying to narrow down the possible reasons for this, but as of now I'm stumped. Should I put all my barba functions in separate document? I've tried wrapping the barba initialization in a 'document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {//stuff here}); function, tried restarting fullpage.js using '$.fn.fullpage.reBuild();' as described in fullpage's documentation and still nothing? At this point, I'm wondering if I should buckle down & rebuild this project using React... whatever works!